# Response Data is not binding to table with ng-repeat in Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new one in Angula JS, I am trying to bind a table, but ng-repeat is not getting bind in table. I can see the data when i check in console. There is no error message also displaying.My sample code is
Partial View

```
<h3>List of Players</h3>
{{message}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="player in listPlayers">
        <td>{{player.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{player.Club}}</td>
        <td>{{player.Country}}</td>
        <td>{{player.Age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My controller code is

```
angular.module("CrudDemoApp.controllers", []).
    controller("MainController", function ($scope, PlayerService) {
        $scope.message = "Main Controller";
        PlayerService.GetPlayersFromDB().then(function (d) {   
            $scope.listPlayers = d.data.list;
            console.log($scope.listPlayers);
        });
    })
```

My App.js code is

```
var app = angular.module("CrudDemoApp", ["CrudDemoApp.controllers", "ngRoute"]);
app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/Partials/PlayerList.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        }).
        when("/AddPlayer",
        {
            templateUrl: "/Partials/AddPlayer.html",
            controller: "AddPlayerController"
        }).
        when("/EditPlayer/:id", {
            templateUrl: "/Partials/EditPlayer.html",
            controller: "EditPlayerController"
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
    }
])
```

Comment: show your data format ?

Comment: @Rakeschand Its worked, I just cleared browsing history, its done